# Create multiple checkboxes php

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I am trying to create a student attendance table that contains a checkbox for each students attendance, that is to be stored in a database.

This is my table that I have so far, that is executed from an ajax function call. Most of the data is from a database, that contains student names.

For the sake of this example `$numStudent = 5;`

```
echo '<form method="post" action="checkAttend.php"> 
    <table border="1">';
$count = 1;

while(($count < $numStudent) && ($students = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))) {
    echo '<tr>
        <th>' . $count. '</th>
        <th>' . $students['student_name'] . '</th>
        <th> <input type="checkbox" name="students[]" /> </th>
    </tr>';
    $count++;
}

echo '<th colspan = "3">
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" /> </th>';
echo '</table>';
echo '</form>';
```

In `checkAttend.php` The form prints exactly the way I need it to, but when I try to print out the values in the checkbox array (to check what values are contained within before saving it to the database) each value in the array prints out :

```
$student_attend[0]       A
$student_attend[1]       r
$student_attend[2]       r
$student_attend[3]       a
$student_attend[4]       y
```

Typically I want to store some kind of value in the corresponding field in the database to indicate if the student is absent or not.

I cant tell if I am doing the checkbox loop correctly or not or if I need to add in more stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add dynamic data with your checkboxes, then you can use it as follows:
Inside the form tag you can use

```
    <form method="post" action="checkAttend.php"> 
    <table border="1">
    <?php
    $count=1;
    while($students = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     ?>
     <tr>
      <th><?php echo $count;?></th>
      <th><?php echo $student['student_name']; ?></th>
      <th><input type="checkbox" name="students[]" value=<?php echo $student['student_id']; ?>/></th>
     </tr>
     <?php
    }
    ?>
</table>
</form>
```

and in checkAttend.php page write the following code:

```
if(isset($_POST['button'])){
  if(count($_POST['student_id'])>0){
   foreach($_POST['student_id'] as $student_id){
    mysql_query("update table_name set column_name = '1' where student_id = '".$student_id.'"); 
    // Just use the student id as checkbox value and update it as you just need the check or uncheck the checkbox.  
   }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to loop through the `$student_attend` array like the following:

```
foreach ($student_attend as $value) { 
  // do something with $value
}
```

More info on `foreach` [here](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).